# Incoherent output of CultureInfo in different machines

Tags: .net, winapi, cultureinfo

I am relying on the .NET CultureInfo object to get the parent culture of some custom cultures (custom in the sense that they represent countries paired with unofficial languages, like: 'en-IT' or 'fr-DE').

Everything is working fine but I am facing a problem when it comes to Traditional Chinese (zh-Hant) paired with China (usually it should be paired with Hong Kong).

The problem is: in my development machine (Windows 10) I have a different output than the one I have on the staging server (Windows Server 2008R2) for the "Parent" property of the specific culture.

From this page every "Traditional" culture has "CHT" (LCID 0x7C04) as her parent culture.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent(v=vs.110).aspx

This is the console application that I am running:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.Version.ToString());
        System.Console.WriteLine("zh-Hant-CN");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent Name is: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hant-CN").Parent.Name);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent LCID is: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hant-CN").Parent.EnglishName);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent LCID is: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hant-CN").Parent.LCID);
        System.Console.WriteLine("zh-Hans-CN");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent Name is: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans-CN").Parent.Name);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent Name is: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans-CN").Parent.EnglishName);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Parent LCID is: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans-CN").Parent.LCID);

        System.Console.WriteLine("Same culture: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hant-CN")
           .Equals(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans-CN")).ToString()
        );
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

- Running as compiled exe, in debug, with AnyCpu
- Targeting frameword 4.6.2 (tried with 4.5.0, same results)
- All the latest windows updates installed

The output on my machine (Windows 10) is:

```
4.0.30319.42000
zh-Hant-CN
Parent Name is: zh-CHT
Parent LCID is: Chinese (Traditional) Legacy
Parent LCID is: 31748
zh-Hans-CN
Parent Name is: zh-CHS
Parent Name is: Chinese (Simplified) Legacy
Parent LCID is: 4
Same culture: False
```

The output on: Win Server 2008R2, Win Server 2012R2, Win 8, Win 7. Is:

```
4.0.30319.42000
zh-Hant-CN
Parent Name is: zh-CHS
Parent LCID is: Chinese (Simplified) Legacy
Parent LCID is: 4
zh-Hans-CN
Parent Name is: zh-CHS
Parent Name is: Chinese (Simplified) Legacy
Parent LCID is: 4
Same culture: True
```

Any idea of what can be the cause, or where the cultures are stored (.Net / Windows) ?

Thank you.

PS: please excuse my bad english.

### UPDATE

I did dig deeper in the rabbit hole....
From the source code of the framework (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/culturedata.cs,b7941d5fc1e6626d,references) I found that, at lower levels, the *GetLocaleInfoEx* (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API is called to retrieve the parent culture name...

Doing more tests I have found that, calling that Api with 'zh-Han?-*' results in a `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, but apparently only on non-windows 10 machines...

So I am going to add more tags to the question.

### Update #2

Not only the Traditional Chinese has a Simplified Chinese as Parent, even the Simplified Chinese created with "zh-Hans-CN" has the wrong DateTimeFormat associated: for example the month names are expressed in Traditional chinese (一月) instead of the Simplified version (1月)

I.e. this code outputs 'Same month: true' only on Windows < 10:

`Console.WriteLine("Same month: " + CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hant-TW").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[0].Equals(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans-CN").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[0]).ToString());`

Comment: I would create a separate object variable and check its members during debugging, instead of just printing the `Parent` property. This might give you more helpful info. // `zh-CHS` is wrong, and it has the LCID 0x0004. `zh-CHT` is 0x7c04, maybe the function on 2008R2 returns only lower bytes? // Is there a relation to installed languages (I don't think so actually)?

Comment: I don't know, this instruction prints "True": Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hant-CN").Equals(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-Hans-CN")));

Comment: True on both PCs? Are you running in VS debuging or EXE? Do you have one and the same EXE on both PCs, or compiled and run on both separately? // this might also help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997383(v=vs.100).aspx#new_neutral_cultures

Comment: Windows 8: same result like what?

Comment: Compiled EXE on both pcs.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Do you know where are the Cultures stored? In the .Net Framework or in Windows?

Comment: No idea, sorry. // you should give your test program to other users and compare their results wih yours. Also, a clear overview of your tests and results may help to get more support. I don' t get what you have tested where with which result. Which OS, which .net? Same result from VS and EXE on compiling PC? Do systematic tests to find possible bugs. And: try with regular language combinations, too!

Comment: Having similar (same?) issue: `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)` --> I thougth all cultures are returned (813 on my W10 machine)... but e.g. **zh-CN (LCID: 2052)** is not in the array... But when doing `new CultureInfo("zh-CN");` I get a valid CultureInfo object...